# My Ubuntu Disks won't boot. What am I doing wrong

Tags: live-cd

I have been using Linux disks that I have received in magazines and now I want to get a 64 bit version of Xubuntu 12.10 (the magazine came with Xubuntu 12.04 32bit).

So making a disk should be this easy right?
Download .iso then burn it to a dvd. After that boot it into the computer using BIOS.

When I go to do this the drive starts to read the disk, then it stops.it does not work it just goes directly back to my old OS (Ubuntu 12.04).

Am I doing something wrong?

I put the write speed at 2.4x which is the slowest my burner goes. I thought that would fix the issue, but no.

Comment: Are you sure you are "Burning an image to disk", and not "creating a data disk" that contains the ISO?

Comment: That is probably my error. I will give that a shot.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question that might occour to others and that others might ask (or enter in google) in the same way. I don't think people should downvote this.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are "Burning an image to disk", and not "creating a data disk" that contains the ISO?

[image: Disk from image in Brasero]

Answer (score 0):

An ISO can be compared to a compressed file like a .zip or tar.bz2.  It contains all the system files that make Ubuntu work.  In order to create a liveCD you need to *extract* the files from the ISO.  You do this with a program that knows how to extract the insides of the ISO and then move *those* files to the CD/DVD.  You can do this with Brasero disk creator, like another answer says.

So, when you burned your disk you were putting the *ISO* on the disk, when you really needed the *contents* of the ISO on the disk.